# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Neo4jClient.NodeReference<>' to 'Neo4jClient.GraphClient'

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

This is a two part question

1. I am getting this error when i try to create a new node

   Cannot implicitly convert type'Neo4jClient.NodeReference' to 'Neo4jClient.GraphClient'

I have 3 classes here
The first connects to the GraphDB server and return the client variable for later use in other classes

```
public GraphClient GetConnection()
        {
            var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
            client.Connect();
            return client;
        }
```

Then there is the New_Node class that looks like this

```
 class New_Node
    {
        public GraphClient Node { get; set; }
    }
```

Then there is the Graph Operations class that has the CreateNode Method

```
public GraphClient CreateNode()
{
    Graph_Connection connection = new Graph_Connection();
    var NewNode = connection.GetConnection();
    var Created_Node = NewNode.Create(new New_Node());
    return Created_Node;
}
```

1. how do I set the property of the Node on another line of code instead of creating them with the node, I want to make my app more dynamic, where as this way seems very hard coded

   var refA = client.Create(new Person() { Name = "Person A" });

In Java one can do this

```
Node user1 = this.graphDb.createNode(); 
user1.setProperty("name", "Mike");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to persist the DB connection inside the node itself.

Here's your definition of the node's *data structure*:

```
class New_Node
{
    public GraphClient Node { get; set; }
}
```

That says that you want a property on the node called "Node" that holds the connection to the DB that contains the node. Tongue twisted yet? Mine is.

Based on your Java comparison, I think you want your node to actually look like this:

```
class New_Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

That says you want a node with a Name property, which is a string.

Then, you can create it like so:

```
graphClient.Create(new New_Node { Name = "Mike" });
```

In relation to your sub question, "1.how do I set the property of the Node on another line of code instead of creating them with the node", when you call `graphClient.Create` we are persisting it to the DB. Any later property changes are updates to the DB, and more calls.

Just call create when your node is ready to be persisted.

```
var node = new New_Node();
... think ...
node.Name = "Mike";
... think ...
graphClient.Create(node);
```

Basically, every time you call `graphClient.Something` we hit the DB. This is because we're going over a stateless API. This is different to the Java driver which is talking to the DB in memory (assuming you're talking about an embedded Neo4j instance).

HTH.

-- Tatham